# How to clone record using custom setting?

Tags: apex

i want to write a generic method to clone object.So how to clone an object using custom setting  in apex (in custom setting we define object and fields).

Comment: Hi Ankita, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. As written, this question is far too broad to be on topic and doesn't demonstrate a good faith effort on your part to even begin solving the problem. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am trying to write a generic method where i am passing sObject and list of fields from custom setting but not able to understand how to write a generic method .                                                                                                                    private void cloneOpportunity(list<sObject> lstsObject,list<string> lstFieldsName,set<id> setRecordId){logic here..}.Please help!

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post with any clarifications, and demonstrate what you have tried so far and be specific about what did not work. Also, please refrain from supplications for additional help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The four basic steps based on what you have in your comment would be to:

1.Use the fields to build the query,

```
String QueryString = 'SELECT Id';
QueryString += String.join(lstFieldsName,',');
QueryString += ' FROM ' + SObjectName + ' WHERE Id IN (\'';
QueryString += String.join(new list<Id>(setRecordId),'\',\'');
QueryString += '\')';
```

2.Query the records

```
list<sObject> Records = Database.query(QueryString);
```

3.Clone them

```
list<sObject> NewRecords = Records.deepClone(false,false,false);
```

4.Add the clones to the database

```
Database.insert(NewRecords);
```